# Sync ASP.NET website with web server?

Tags: asp.net, ftp, visual-studio-2013, iis-8

I have an IIS 8 web server with FTP access configured. On my development PC, I created a new ASP.NET project with Visual Studio 2013. How can I "publish" / upload my project to the web server on build? I noticed that while creating a project, I can choose "FTP" to create the files on the webserver, but then Visual Studio doesn't create the folder structure, include jquery, sample code, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Visual Studio you can create a publish profile and configure your FTP server on it. Then, after the publish profile is created, you can use the "One-Click Publish" feature to send the files to your server. It even has some preview options, that allow you to see the changes that are being made.

Here is a link from Microsoft describing the entire process: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337(v=vs.110).aspx

And here is another useful link from Microsoft containing an overview of the web deployment process for Visual Studio and ASP.Net applications

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394698(v=vs.110).aspx

Both links are targeted to Visual Studio 2012, but i think they also apply for VS 2013

Comment: Web Deploy was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!